# Is this sequence uniformly convergent??

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm just going through a few practice papers and I came across a problem I am having some trouble with so would appreciate some help. The function is $\frac{\log(x)}{x^n}$ for $x\geq 1$. Now I know that for $x = 1$ obviously the limit is $0$ as $n\to\infty$, but for $x > 1$ is it acceptable to say that even though both $\log(x)$ and $x^n$ go to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity, because $x^n$ shoots off alot faster the limit still heads to $0$? Also I am unsure how to calculate whether this is uniformly convergent, that's if it is indeed pointwise because I'm having trouble finding a supremum.

Comment: Can you locate the critical points of $f_n\colon x \mapsto \frac{\log x}{x^n}$?

Comment: do you have to choose both the x and the n values for that? I've never actually found critical points for more than the one variable

Comment: $n$ is an index. For a fixed (but arbitrary) $n$, can you find the critical points of $x \mapsto \frac{\log x}{x^n}$?

Comment: then does that mean that x needs to equal 0?

Comment: The domain that is considered is $[1,+\infty)$. $x$ can't be $0$. What is the derivative (with respect to $x$) of $x \mapsto \frac{\log x}{x^n}$?

Comment: oh yes, I had forgotten that x must be greater than 1. the derivative is        -x^(-n-1)*(n*ln(x)-1). The best I can seem to do is by making x=e then        -nx^(-n-1) = -x^(-n-1)  which only works when n=1

Comment: When is $(n\log x - 1) = 0$?

Comment: oh, when x = e^(1/n)?

Comment: Right. And that helps because …?

Comment: because that means e^(1/n) is the supremum of the function but because that only ever tends to 0 as n goes to infinity it means the function is pointwise convergent but not uniformly convergent?

Comment: $e^{1/n}$ is not the supremum. It's the (only) critical point. What does that tell you about the values?

Comment: would that then not mean there is no supremum?

Comment: It's the point where the function attains its supremum, not the supremum of the function. But that the function has a maximum there doesn't directly follow from the fact that it's the only critical point, you need to use some other properties of the functions to deduce that. When that is done, looking at $f_n(e^{1/n})$ tells you whether the sequence converges uniformly or not.

Comment: well from the material we've been taught in lectures I just don't know where to go from here, I think im just going to have to hope this question doesn't come up in the exam tomorrow

Comment: Come on, we're close. What is $f_n(e^{1/n})$?

Comment: the nth root of e?

Comment: That's $e^{1/n}$. Evaluate $f_n\colon x \mapsto \frac{\log x}{x^n}$ there.

Comment: oh yes of course, well then that would be 1/x^2n

Comment: No. What is $\log (e^{1/n})$? What is $(e^{1/n})^n$?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to substitute the denominator, we would have 1/ne

Comment: Good. Does that, together with the fact that $\frac{\log x}{x^n}\geqslant 0$, give you uniform convergence, or is more needed?

Comment: So that means that the function is uniformly convergent which can be shown by making n larger than (1/e)*epsilon right?

Comment: Wrong placement of parentheses, $\frac{1}{e\cdot \varepsilon}$.

Comment: ah yes, my mistake. thankyou very much for your help and your patience